# how to write a conditional statement the right way

Tags: javascript

I am Learning JavaScript and in the courses I am following we are at the conditional statements, 
now I have too
Write a series of conditional statements that:

> - prints "not a group" if musicians is less than or equal to 0
> - prints "solo" if musicians is equal to 1
> - prints "duet" if musicians is equal to 2
> - prints "trio" if musicians is equal to 3
> - prints "quartet" if musicians is equal to 4
> - prints "this is a large group" if musicians is greater than 4

So then

> If **musicians** equals 3, then *trio* should be printed to the console.
>   If **musicians** equals 20, then *this is a large group* should be printed to the console.
>   If **musicians** equals -1, then *not a group* should be printed to the console. etc.

So I entered the following code

```js
var musicians = 200; // Change this variable too test your code


if (musicians === 1){
  console.log("solo");
}else if (musicians === 2){
  console.log("duet");
}else if (musicians === 3){
  console.log("trio");
}
else if (musicians === 4){
  console.log("quartet");
}else if (musicians > 4){
  console.log("This is a large group");
}else {
  console.log("this is not a group");
}
```

But I keep getting the same feedback

> Try again
>   **What Went Well**
>    - Your code should have a variable musicians
>    - Your code should include a conditional statement
>   **What Went Wrong**
>    - Verify that your conditional statements are producing the correct output (REMEMBER: Test your code with different values)

I am really trying to grasp this concept of conditional statements but it's frustrating they don't give any additional feedback or tips on how to solve this
So hopefully somebody out here can help and also explain how this works.

Comment: If the assignment is automatically checked by a computer, the output must be *exactly* the same as in the description. If the output should be "this is a large group", then "This is a large group" (with a capital T) will fail. Similarly if the output should be "not a group" then "this is not a group" will fail. Copy-paste the responses from the assignment to your own code to make sure that it's identical.

Comment: I think the problem is "This is a large group" - it should be "this is a large group" with a lower case "t"

Comment: I would prefer switch case instead of multiple if else statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final else should be "not a group",
check case-sensitive,quotations etc.
you are saying prints so try printing the values to document

Comment: Thank you sir for pointing out that typo.
It was "not a group" instead of "this is not a group"